# When adding a web service reference, I can't get all properties of an object

Tags: vb.net, web-services, xsd

I'm using VB.Net in Visual Studio 2012 for a project with a web service I can't change at all. The problem is that VB does not generate all the properties it should generate.

I added the web service as a reference service. According to the XSD, collectionRAEEDataType class should include properties as receiver, referenceNumber, sigCode. But, when I try to access them, two of them are not shown: sigCode and responsabilitySystemData.

I've contacted the support email of the web service and they tell me that yes, that in the Java service the class is generated with those fields:

```
public class CollectionRAEEDataType {
protected String sigCode;
protected RegisteredInfoDataType responsabilitySystemData;
...
}
```

But in Reference.vb I get this:

```
Partial Public Class collectionRAEEDataType
        Inherits Object
        Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged

        Private itemField As Object

        Private receiverField As receiverType

        Private referenceNumberField As String

        Private assignmentOfficeIdField As String

        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("responsabilitySystemData", GetType(registeredInfoDataType), Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order:=0),  _
         System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("sigCode", GetType(collectionRAEEDataTypeSigCode), Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order:=0)>  _
        Public Property Item() As Object
            Get
                Return Me.itemField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.itemField = value
                Me.RaisePropertyChanged("Item")
            End Set
        End Property

        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>  _
        Public Property receiver() As receiverType
            Get
                Return Me.receiverField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.receiverField = value
                Me.RaisePropertyChanged("receiver")
            End Set
        End Property
...
```

As you can see, the property receiver is ok, but responsabilitySystemData and sigCode are not properties.

Do you know how could I solve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Modifiers protected String sigCode;

Comment: If they let that modifiers I will be unable to get the properties?

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself. I had to instantiate the Item field with the type I wanted, registeredInfoDataType or collectionRAEEDataTypeSigCode.

For example,

```
MyElement.Item = New registeredInfoDataType()
```

Thank you.